# Python module for ganglia - precision number being rounded by gmond

Tags: python, int, precision, ganglia

I've written a python module for ganglia that is returning response times.  The raw times look like this:

0.0120489597321

I parse this with my python module and return the time as such:

```
return int(response_time)
```

If I run the script with python, it works fine:

```
[ DEBUG ]: returning: 0.0120489597321
```

However, gmond (ganglia) runs this module and it rounds the result to 0.0000.  I am classifying it as a uint.

I've tried to return it as a float, and as long... but both methods of provided the same results.  Anyone have any ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. `int(response_time)` will return an integer, `int(0.0120489597321)` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to multiply that number by 10^6 before reporting to ganglia and then set the ganglia RRA to divide it by 10^6 before graphing.